# Overflow hidden issue with background repeating div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a `div` to repeat a background to 100% of the height of the content inside the wrapper.

I'm using `overflow: hidden` to do this, but this (unsurprisingly) cuts off content at a point dependent on the user's screen resolution.

Removing the `overflow:hidden` line means the background won't repeat at all and the `#wrapper` div doesn't assume the full height of the content.

You can see my code and a preview here - http://jsbin.com/ikuba4/2 - if anyone has any pointers that would be great!

EDIT: To clarify, the issue is that I need my `#wrapper` div (which contains the background image slice repeating vertically) should dynamically extend its height to the height of the #inner_wrapper div - removing `overflow:hidden` results in the `#wrapper` div not extending its height at all, while using `overflow:hidden` extends the height to a point but then content gets cut off.

Comment: What do you mean "repeat background to 100% height"? Stretch the image?

Comment: I mean that the containing #wrapper div (containing the background image slice) should be the full height of the #inner_wrapper div inside it. At the moment, the closest I can get to making this work is using overflow:hidden

Comment: OK, looks like thirtydot answer is what you need? Anyway when commenting on comment use `@` like I did now to notify the person, first three letters are enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `#wrapper`:

- Remove `height: 100%`.
- Remove `overflow: hidden`.

On `#inner_wrapper`:

- Remove `height: 100%`.
- Add `overflow: hidden`.

Testing with Firefox/Firebug, those steps sort it out.

Here is a [***fixed jsBin***](http://jsbin.com/ikuba4/3) which is doing the equivalent of those steps.

Edit:
As @Marnix pointed out in his answer, you should also remove `height: 100%` from `#outer_container` - I don't think there's any need for it to be there.

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot - works perfectly. I'd mistakenly thought that for this type of layout I needed to set all outer containing divs to height: 100%, but that's obviously not the case :)

Answer (score 2):

A little different which works as well:

`#outer_container`

- remove `height: 100%`

`#wrapper`

- remove `height: 100%`

`#inner_wrapper`

- remove `height:100%`
- add `overflow:auto`

Comment: +1 for noticing the useless `height: 100%` on `#outer_container`.